# Mysql full-text search does not work

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

**Here is my database code . the problem result showing 0 instead of 1**

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `house_details` (
   `houses_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

   `everything_search` text NOT NULL

    FULLTEXT KEY `everything_search` (`everything_search`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 


    INSERT INTO `house_details` (`everything_search`) VALUES
     ('Good very good new-market Mymenshing Family sourov 4564'),
```

**here is my database query command**

```
SELECT * FROM house_details WHERE MATCH (everything_search) AGAINST ('Mymenshing') > 0   ORDER BY `houses_id` DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

**and result is **
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0013 sec )

Comment: I've never seen `> 0` in this context, remove it?

Comment: The search result is empty because the word you're searching for is present in at least 50% of the rows (ie. one row) You need a larger dataset.

Comment: ^ +1, forgot about the infamous MySQL 50% rule

Comment: don't use `select *`, try `select col1,col2,...colN`

Comment: Anyone ever reading these comments, please ignore what @jcho360 posted.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me in boolean mode:

```
SELECT * FROM house_details WHERE MATCH (everything_search) 
AGAINST ('Mymenshing' In Boolean mode) > 0   ORDER BY `houses_id` DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

take a look here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4471/6

after make some reasearch I found that there's a bug with the match-agains in Mysql: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19583

and here is how fix the 'stopwords': http://www.nivas.hr/blog/2009/09/15/how-to-disable-mysql-fulltext-stopwords/http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4471/6

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `>0` in the where clause:

```
        SELECT * FROM house_details 
        WHERE MATCH (everything_search) AGAINST ('Mymenshing')
        ORDER BY `houses_id` DESC LIMIT 0,3 ;
```